# why run and start call simultaneously in java

Tags: java

I am learning a tutorial about how to consume json web service.

But I have two doubts can you please help me in understanding.

I am learning from this link
http://codeoncloud.blogspot.in/2013/05/blackberry-java-json-tutorial.html

Here is one class extend by thread

```
public class ConnectJson extends Thread {

 private String url;
 public String response;
 private String myinterface = ";interface=wifi";

  public void run() {
         HttpConnection conn = null;
         InputStream in = null;
         int code;

   try {
      conn = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(this.url + this.myinterface, Connector.READ);
         conn.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);
         code = conn.getResponseCode();

         if (code == HttpConnection.HTTP_OK) {
             in = conn.openInputStream();
             ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

             byte[] buffer = new byte[in.available()];
             int len = 0;

             while (-1 != (len = in.read(buffer))) {
                 out.write(buffer);                   
             }

             out.flush();
             this.response = new String(out.toByteArray());

             if (out != null){
                 out.close();
             }
             if (in != null){
                 in.close();
             }
             if (conn != null){
                 conn.close();
             }
         }

     } catch (Exception e) {
        Dialog.inform(e.toString());
     }
}  

public String jsonResult(String url){
  this.url = url;
  this.start();
  this.run();
  return response;
 }
}
```

It is making one object of that class and call method of that class .In that method it call start as well as run method why ?

```
this.start();
this.run();?
```

Comment: The code is incorrect.  To work correctly, it shouldn't be a Thread and it shouldn't call start();

Answer (score 2):

> In that method it call start as well as run method why ?

You'd have to ask the author of the code; looking at that class's code, it looks incorrect. It's also fairly unusual.

In the normal course of things, you don't call `run` directly; you start the thread (with `start`) and *the JVM* is then responsible for creating a new thread and calling `run` on it.

You *can* call `run` yourself if you really want that code to run right away on the current thread, but it's unusual and that class doesn't immediately look like it's designed to do that correctly. What that code actually does is start a new thread (which means `run` will eventually get called on that new thread), but then as you observed it *also* calls `run` directly. So `run` will run twice, and may well run twice *simultaneously*. Since the code in `run` uses instances variables that will be used by both threads but doesn't do anything to coordinate access to those instance variables...well, again, it looks incorrect.

I don't think I'd keep following that tutorial. You may find the [Concurrency trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html) in the Java tutorials from Oracle might be useful. (Threads are part of it.)

Comment: Things may not be as bleak as you portray them. Maybe the point is in getting two concurrent executions of `run`, and that is what is actually achieved. There is no rule stating you must not call `Thread#run`. A Thread is a Runnable, after all.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Hmmm, very good point. You should post an answer explaining that for the OP. But looking at the code in that class, I don't think it's meant to be run that way.

Comment: I went to the original page and you are right, that guy has no idea what he's doing. Here's a quote from that page: "In Blackberry we cannot make a HTTP call in main thread, therefore we need to create separate thread to create the HTTP call." Yet making an HTTP call from the main thread is precisely what he *is* doing.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Yeah, and given what `run` does... Anyway, I updated the answer based on your point that you *can* do this, provided you know what you're doing, which as you say doesn't appear to be true in that author's case. :-)

Comment: @user2648752: What Marko and I are saying is that while it *can* be correct to call both `start` and `run`, in this case it's much more likely that the author of that code has just made a mistake. I've reworded the answer (you may have to refresh) to try to clarify.

Comment: @user2648752: Yes, it is incorrect, and in more than one way. I would recommend finding another one.

Comment: i have one more question ..if i am getting data on from serve .and show that data in list..so can I make another thread for getting the data from server

Comment: or make function inside that function same code is written in run method .call that method and then show data on list

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44093/discussion-between-user2648752-and-t-j-crowder)